# What is wrong with OrderBy Linq Extension in EF4?

Tags: .net-4.0, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have following two calls, both are same but results are different...

It is simple console application with connection to local database.

```
DBContext db = new DBContext();
```

This one sorts as expected,

```
var q = from x in db.Cities
        orderby x.CountryCode, x.City
        select x;

foreach(var x in q){
   Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}",x.CountryCode, x.City);
}
```

But why this one does not sort by City, it only sorts by CountryCode

```
foreach(var x in db.Cities.OrderBy(d=>d.City).OrderBy(d=>d.CountryCode)){
   Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}",x.CountryCode, x.City);
}
```

If I change order of OrderBy statements, then only Last OrderBy seem to work correctly but intermediate OrderBy has no impact at all. Is this bug in EF or Linq extensions?

I have no problem in rewriting queries but I want to know what is wrong with OrderBy Linq Extension method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a blog post about this: http://www.kristofclaes.be/blog/2010/07/06/order-on-multiple-fields-with-linq/

The problem is that the second `OrderBy()` overrules the first one. To fix this, you can replace the second `OrderBy()` with `ThenBy()` like this:

```
db.Cities.OrderBy(d=>d.City).ThenBy(d=>d.CountryCode)
```

Comment: Well this is just because of ignorance, I didnt read MSDN, I just assumed it should work :)

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one who made that false assumption :-)

Answer (score 1):

Change the second OrderBy to ThenBy.